# How To Create Primary Key In Firebase FireStore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On my site, I am giving an option to set the unique user name

it's unique so no same user name can be placed

Comment: The document ID is the primary key. Once set it cannot be changed and a collection can have only 1 doc with same ID. Or you could reserve a field in the document itself to be used as one.

Comment: If you [search for `[google-cloud-firestore] unique username`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+unique+username), you'll find this topic has been covered before. I recommend checking out those questions and answers, and trying to implement your use-case based on that. --- If you have more concrete problems after that, post a question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck and it is more likely that someone can help.

Comment: FILE 1 :---

let a ='No Data';

Function  changeA(){
a='Value Of A Is Changed';
}
chnageA();
alert(a);

export{a};

FILE 2 :--

import {a} from 'File1 Path';

alert(a);